# Nginx proxy_pass cookies

Tags: php, apache, cookies, nginx

What we have:

- A bunch of apache nginx.
- Forum Tinyboard.

Through Apache authorization is proceeding normally, but with nginx as a function mkhash:

```
    function mkhash($username, $password, $salt = false) {
    global $config;

    if (! $salt) {
    // Create some sort of salt for the hash
     $salt = substr(base64_encode(sha1(rand(). time(), true). $config['cookies']['salt']), 0 , 15) ;

     $generated_salt = true;
    }

     // Generate hash (method is not important as long as it's strong)
     $hash = substr(base64_encode(md5($username . $config['cookies']['salt']. sha1($username . $password . $salt . ($config['mod']['lock_ip']? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']:''), true), true)), 0 , 20);

    if (isset($generated_salt))
     return array($hash, $salt);
    else
     return $hash;
    }
```

does not return the correct value and the authorization fails. 
Verification is as follows:

```
    if ($cookie[ 1 ]! == mkhash($cookie[0], $user['password'], $cookie[2] ) {
     // Malformed cookies
     destroyCookies();
     mod_login();
     exit;
    }
```

In order to be successful login condition should not be executed.

Example returned values ​​via nginx (login fails):

- cookie0: admin
- cookie1: Ib37H5U7hCi6Br9M09V
- cookie2: Nn2wUxlnirvgzkn
- mkhash: fN1jv3t9ccThde0Kp30h

Example returned values ​​​​via apache (login success):

- cookie0: admin
- cookie1: SgaMoQ07upLoz9Q7Wdz6
- cookie2: Zp6BQ2b20Jsh 1R
- mkhash: SgaMoQ07upLoz9Q7Wdz6

Apache hanging on port 82 (if handled properly on that port authentication is successful). Nginx itself takes only static files, dynamic content is taken from Apache. In what could be the reason?

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        proxy_send_timeout 120;
        proxy_read_timeout 180;
    }
```

Comment: This is probably not related to your php code, but your server configuration. Try to debug the cookie values with echo or similar to make sure they are passed by nginx, and if they are not post your nginx proxy_pass configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your hash generation you make use of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

This will be always set to 127.0.0.1.

you need to change this to `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']` to get the same IP address (X-Real-IP is what you have defined in your nginx.conf)